# Wrappning one element with another in HTML

Tags: html

```
<div>
 <span>oneoneoneone</span>
 <span>twooneoneone</span>
 <span>threeoneoneone</span>
</div>
```

By nature it displays "span"s in one line without a break.

```
<div style="position:absolute;background:red">
 <div style="position:absolute">
 <span>oneoneoneone</span>
 <span>twooneoneone</span>
 <span>threeoneoneone</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

It displays the span elements one below the other. I know it's a silly question,but I am curious to know the fact!My question is that why inline elements behave like a block level elements here? Any good guy from stackoverflow...

Comment: I have editted my question. why inline elements behave like block level elements here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` elements are inline elements which means they will always take up the space on a line before wrapping to the next line.

In the first example you have a normal `div` which is a block level element that will take up the whole line (100% width).  This means the spans will not wrap unless the width is less than all three words.

In the second example, you have an absolutely positioned `div`.  As you have not given this `div` a width, it will be as wide as the largest non-breaking element inside it - which is one of the words in your span.  As the `div` is now only as wide as a word, the spans will wrap.

[This fiddle shows your second absolutely positioned div is only as wide as the largest non-breaking element](http://jsfiddle.net/fz8Lc/)

[Have a look at this to understand block and inline elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/)

Comment: I am still confused! As I tried to change position of the (1) outer div to relative inner div to absolute (2) outer div to absolute inner div to relative (3) only single div with position absolute. In all the cases the span elements display in just one line without a line break. Why is this? @Pete

Comment: All the elements are still on a single line as you aren't giving a width to your absolute div - you need to give the absolute div a width that is larger than the length of all the words together if you want them t stay on the same line

Answer (score 1):

Because by default a  is a block element that takes up the full width of the container it's in.  "position:absolute" removes that width.  If you set "width:100%;" to the elements with absolute positioning, the spans will again be on one line without a break.

Comment: I am still confused! As I tried to change position of the (1) outer div to relative inner div to absolute (2) outer div to absolute inner div to relative (3) only single div with position absolute. In all the cases the span elements display in just one line without a line break. Why is this? @Dan Goodspeed

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle examples of what you mean?